Will the future of the universe be an expansion-contraction-re-expansion-re-contraction cycle?
maybe the universe will have an， expansion-contraction-re-expansion-re-contraction cycle in the future. Dark matter and dark energy are in balance with each other, and the universe will not expand/contract to such extreme states as "big tearing", "big squeezing" and "big cooling". Is this assumption true? Is there any evidence that it is relatively correct?
Compared with the universe going through the big bang-big squeeze cycle, I believe that the universe may have the cycle of "expansion-contraction-re-expansion", so that the universe will not be torn or squeezed repeatedly.

The evidence points to "no",  dark energy will tend to lead to an acceleration in expansion, and "big cooling" (if that means what I think it means)

"Dark matter and dark energy are in balance with each other". No. If they were in balance the expansion wouldn't be accelerating. There is no evidence or accepted theoretical possibility of a future contraction phase.

I wager it's anyone's guess now and it's not likely to quickly change.
